# bind repeater with multi list<>

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, repeater, generic-list

I want to bind multi list with repeater.But I am getting some error on binding.Please help

This list is as parent child list.
I am getting error

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll

but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'Questionm' does not contain a property with the name 'Answer'.

```
    **code**
    **class Name:**

    public   class Questionm
    {
        public  int QID { get; set; }
         public  string Question { get; set; }
        public  int AnswerType { get; set; }
         public  List<ChildLayers> ChildLayers { get; set; }
        public  Questionm()
        {
            ChildLayers = new List<ChildLayers>();
        }

    }

    public class ChildLayers
    {
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }

**ASPX.cs Code**

 public void daya()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); //
        cmd.CommandText = "selectdata";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DT = ds.Tables["Table"];
        DataTable DT1 = new DataTable();
        DT1 = ds.Tables["Table1"];

        IList<Questionm> data = ConvertDataTable<Questionm>(DT);
        IList<ChildLayers> cdata = ConvertDataTable<ChildLayers>(DT1);
         IList<Questionm> hierarcy = new List<Questionm>();

        List<Questionm> dsfsadsad = new List<Questionm>();
         foreach (var layer in data)
        {
        Questionm obj = new Questionm();

            obj.QID = layer.QID;
            obj.Question = layer.Question;
            obj.AnswerType =layer.AnswerType;     
        var sublayers1 = cdata.Where(i => i.QuestionID == layer.QID && i.QuestionID != 0);

        foreach (var sublayer in sublayers1)
        {
            ChildLayers obj1 = new ChildLayers();
            obj1.Answer = sublayer.Answer;
            obj1.QuestionID = sublayer.QuestionID;

            obj.ChildLayers.Add(obj1);

        }
        hierarcy.Add(obj);

    }

        rptparent.DataSource = hierarcy;
        rptparent.DataBind();
 }

**.aspx code**
 <asp:repeater id="rptparent" runat="server"> 
  　    <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
         <tr>
                <th>Question</th>

        </tr>   
    </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%# ((Questionm)Container.DataItem).QID %>
          </td>

            <%# ((Questionm)Container.DataItem).Question %>

            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Answer") %>' />
            <%--Answer  Text='<%# Eval("FileName") %>'>--%>


        </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>      
        </table><br />
    </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:repeater></td></tr>
```

Now i ma getting this error
[image]

An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'Questionm' does not contain a property with the name 'Answer'.

Comment: `Eval("Answer") `  trying to access `Answer` property on `Questionm` class while there is no such property in that class that's why you are getting this error. You need to avoid that. Can you tell us why you are trying to access `Answer` property `Questionm`?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the exception that, you are accessing an invalid property name from the data source list. Property name `'Answer'` does not exist in your list object.

Questionm does not have 'Answer' property.

EDIT: As you have declared a list type property inside Questionm class, you need to iterate over the class to access 'Answer' property.

Example:

```
((Questionm)Container.DataItem).Question.ChildLayers[0].Answer
```

Comment: i have listed this  public  List<ChildLayers> ChildLayers { get; set; } in Questionm  class .so child layer parameter should be accessible.